# how to convert unicode text to utf8 text readable?

Tags: character-encoding, codepages, mojibake

I got a serious problem regarding Unicode and utf8,
I saved a paragraph of Arabic/Persian text file into notepad and saved it, now I saw my information like

```
Êæ Çíä ÓæÑÓ ÈÑäÇãå ÚÏÏ ÏáÎæÇåí Ñæ ÇÒ æÑæÏí ãííÑå æ Èå Øæá åãæä ÚÏÏ ãËáËí Ñæ ÑÓã ãí ˜äå
```

my question is how to get back my data, it is important for me to get this data back, thanks in advance

Comment: The `open` box in Notepad has a dropdown called `Encoding` - just set it to `UTF-8`. P.S. If this question is actually about *writing a program* to read the UTF-8 data, edit the question and make that more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paragraph was scrambled by saving as code page 1256 (Arabic/Persian), then interpreted as code page 1252 (Western Europe), and finally saved as Unicode text. You can use C# to reverse this procedure:

```
string scrambled = "Êæ Çíä ÓæÑÓ ÈÑäÇãå ÚÏÏ ÏáÎæÇåí Ñæ ÇÒ æÑæÏí ãííÑå æ " + 
                   "Èå Øæá åãæä ÚÏÏ ãËáËí Ñæ ÑÓã ãí ˜äå";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252").GetBytes(scrambled);
string plainText = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256").GetString(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

The plain text output is:
"تو اين سورس برنامه عدد دلخواهي رو از ورودي ميگيره و به طول همون عدد مثلثي رو رسم مي کنه"

Comment: prefect ! can you tell me what you concatenate with:
string scrambled = "Êæ Çíä ÓæÑÓ ÈÑäÇãå ÚÏÏ ÏáÎæÇåí Ñæ ÇÒ æÑæÏí ãííÑå æ " + 
                   "Èå Øæá åãæä ÚÏÏ ãËáËí Ñæ ÑÓã ãí ˜äå";

Comment: It is merely cosmetic. I split the string into two parts to prevent scrollbars from appearing in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you can use Gedit to open it as a 1256 encoded file:

```
gedit shahnameh.txt --encoding WINDOWS-1256
```

You can do the same work via gui. You just need select the correct encoding from "open" dialog box when opening a file. It should be at the bottom of the open dialog.