# python reverse unicode text into readable

Tags: python-3.x, bookmarks, python-unicode, data-recovery, unicode-escapes

i believe i have similar problem to this [how to convert unicode text to utf8 text readable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621433/how-to-convert-unicode-text-to-utf8-text-readable) but i want a python 3.7 solution to it

i am a complete newbie, i have some experience with python so i am trying to use it to make a script that will convert a Unicode file into the previous readable text it was.
the file is a bookmark file i have recovered using easeusa then i opened the bookmark file and it is writen in unicode something like "&PŽ¾³kÊ
k-7ÄÜÅe–?XBdyÃ8ß¯r×»Ê*ã¥bÏñ ¥»X§ÈÕÀ¬Zé‚1öÄEdýŽ‹*€†.c"
whereas previously is said something like " "checksum": "112d56adbd0caa2b3693bb0442dd16ff",
   "roots": {
      "bookmark_bar": {
         "children":"

fyi when i click save as for the unicode bookmark file, for unicode it has ANSI and not utf-8 maybe it was saved us ANSI, i might be waffling here but i'm just trying to give you all the information you might need to help me
 i am a newbie who depressingly need help

Answer (score 0):

This text isn't "Unicode". It's simply gibberish.

This file has been corrupted -- it may have been overwritten with other data before you were able to recover it. It is unlikely to be recoverable.

Comment: but how come the file still has the same size file as before?

Comment: Because that's how large your recovery tool made it.